# Redirect non WWW site to https:// IIS

Tags: http, redirect, iis, https, dns

We have a non WWW website that we want to redirect to https://

The site is being hosted on IIS and we were looking to just type websitename.domain.com and have it redirect to https:// We have a URL rewrite rule in place but it when typing in the websitename.domain.com, it won't even try to go to https:// or http:// Is there something else we have to set for this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Edit the question to include your rule.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you bind the site bindings with websitename.domain.com for HTTP and https protocol like below:

[image]

Try below rule to redirect http to https:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```